# Same server with multiple instances of sonar (different versions) and different SQL Server version for each instance of sonar

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, multiple-instances

We have an instance of Sonar 3.7.3 on a server with Windows Server 2008 R2 and Databases on another dedicated server with SQL Server 2008 R2. 
Would it be possible to install on this Sonar server another instance of sonar with version 5.3 but the databases in SQL Server 2012? Is it supported?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, You need to change the configuration, because the default port for sonar to run is 9000. And two versions can not run in same port. You need to change the config in sonar.properties located in conf folder i.e.:

```
#sonar.web.port=9000
```

file name : conf\sonar.properties

And about DB, it should support.

Comment: Note that you might also have to change `sonar.search.port`, and, if the embedded database is used, `sonar.embeddedDatabase.port`.